# "Uncaught Cannot extend unknown button type: copyHtml5" - How to use `datatables.net-buttons-bs4`

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, datatables

I have installed Datatables via npm:

```
npm install --save datatables.net-bs4
npm install --save datatables.net-buttons-bs4
```

and want to use the `buttons.html5` js file too. 
Before I started working with npm packages I used datatables CDNs like this:

```
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Now I import it like this:

```
// Datatables
import 'datatables.net-bs4';
// Datatables - Buttons
import 'datatables.net-buttons-bs4';
```

My script uses the buttons.js feature with the HTML5 (file exist in the folder `node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js`. but it seems like it's not imported properly using `import 'datatables.net-buttons-bs4';` 
therefore, resulting the error:

> Uncaught Cannot extend unknown button type: copyHtml5
>   in the console, pointing the a row using the feature:

```
this.tableDownload = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(this[this.tableDisplayed], { ... }
```

Which worked fine when using the CDNs.

How do I get `buttons.html5.js` cooperate with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js'
```

like you can see in the download builder if you pick what you need and switch to the npm tab on the bottom.

> https://datatables.net/download/