# Uncaught Cannot extend unknown button type: excelHtml5

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Trying to create an excel export button using the same code I used in another application.

Unfortunately, I am receiving the following error:

```
Uncaught Cannot extend unknown button type: excelHtml5
```

Here is the portion of code that produces the buttons above the datatable:

```
"dom": 'Bfrtip',
"buttons": [
    {
        text: '<i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search All',
        className: 'searchAll btn btn-success btn-sm',
        action: function (e, dt, node, config)
        {
            $('#searchAllModal').modal('show'); 
        }                       
    },                  
    {
        extend: 'excelHtml5',  /*** here is the problem ***/
        title: 'Matchback Rail Export Results',
        text: '<i class="fa fa-download"></i> Export Results',
        className: 'btn btn-secondary btn-sm',
        customize: function( xlsx ) 
        {
            var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];

            $('row c[r^="A"]', sheet).attr( 's', '2' );
        },
        exportOptions: 
        {
            columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        }
    },
    {
        extend: 'colvis',
        text: '<i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i> Toggle Columns',
        className: 'btn btn-secondary btn-sm'
    }
]
```

The page does not like the "extend: 'excelHtml5'" portion of the code.  There's no problem with the "extend: 'colvis'" portion.

I checked to see what libraries I am using:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Upon creating the question, the first suggestion I was given was this:

["Uncaught Cannot extend unknown button type: copyHtml5" - How to use `datatables.net-buttons-bs4`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096635/uncaught-cannot-extend-unknown-button-type-copyhtml5-how-to-use-datatables)

But that question seems to refer to the .net platform.

What am I missing that will help remove this error?

*** UPDATE ***

I updated the datatables buttons library from 1.5.2 to 1.5.1. In addition, I was missing the following requirements:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5) says that it requires the [Buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) extension and other requirements, do you meet all the requirements?

Comment: I updated my question to include the missing requirements. Thank you, sir.

Comment: It was a pleasure for me to have helped.